# how do you add a role when a reaction is added? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

**Is there a way to add a SPECIFIC role by a reaction?**

no source helped me in this.

I would love an idea or recommendation on how to.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and thus provide us with your code and explain your error. This site doesn't support "Spoon Feeding". We are here to help you with any errors you get but the your try has to be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in this case [`on_raw_reaction_add()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) which triggers when somebody reacts on a message that is loaded in cache. As the message the user reacts on gets loaded in the cache as he reacts on it, this works.

So with the example of [Suvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15853906/suvan):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID')
    messageobj = await channel.send('react to this message to get a role')
    await messageobj.add_reaction('')

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global messageobj

    if payload.message_id != messageobj.id:
        return

    if payload.emoji.name == "":
        role = discord.utils.get(bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles, name="YOUR_ROLE_NAME_HERE")
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: do I have to import anything?
because it says : `NameError: name 'messageobj' is not defined`

Comment: It sends the message and reacts but does not add role to me when I react :(

Comment: Oh oops forgot to edit the `reaction_add` to raw 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on_reaction_add`. This will only trigger if the message still is in the bots message cache. Consider using `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` instead.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
    messageobj = await channel.send('react to this message to get a role')
    await messageobj.add_reaction('')

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
    if payload.message.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "":
        role = discord.utils.get(reaction.message.guild.roles, name="YOUR_ROLE_NAME_HERE")
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: I have tried that code and it says:
`if reaction.message.channel.id != channel`

Comment: What problem are you facing with that code

Comment: there is an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: entire error: `File "(thedirectory)", line 38
if reaction.message.channel.id != channel
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: so the `if reaction.message.channel.id != channel`

is getting an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Oh try this then `if reaction.message.channel.id != channel.id`

Comment: But what exactly? The reaction?